# Predis \ Connection \ ConnectionException Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

When I try to execute my project I've got this exception :
`Predis \ Connection \ ConnectionException`

```
open: C:\wamp\www\laravel-pagination\vendor\predis\predis\lib\Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection.php
     * Helper method to handle connection errors.
     *
     * @param string $message Error message.
     * @param int    $code    Error code.
     */
    protected function onConnectionError($message, $code = null)
    {
        CommunicationException::handle(new ConnectionException($this, "$message [{$this->parameters->scheme}://{$this->getIdentifier()}]", $code));
    }
```

Can anyone help me to solve my problem ?

Comment: Is your Redis server running? How have you configured it in Laravel? What command issues this exception?

Comment: how to know if my server Radis is running ?

Comment: Sincerely, I have absolutely no idea, how to find it out on Windows. Why are you even using it, if you do not even know if it is running?

Comment: I have downloaded a project and i try to run it so i get this error !

Comment: Youd did not stated it, and also you did not put there whole error message.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using Redis, you can change `'driver' => 'redis'` to `'driver' => 'file'` in your `app/config/cache.php` file as well as your `app/config/session.php` file.

Comment: I've got the same problem :( any help ?! the same exeception as before

Answer (score 1):

Is not an elegant solution but you can catch the exception, so in your public/index.php try:

```
try{
    $app->run();
} catch (\Predis\Connection\ConnectionException $ex) {

}
```

and in the catch restart your app after had something useful.

Comment: Having similar issue, why laravel exception handling does not catch that exception?